# JSON Error with "\" in result

Tags: ios, json

I have JSON result with backslash in result

```
"{\"Info\":[{\"Full_Eng_Nmae\":\"salaiman don\",\"email\":\"hkeer020@gmail.com\
```

but can not proccess the result

this is my code:

```
-(void) processRecessionSafetyTipsWithData:(NSData*)data
{


    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary* json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    if (!json || error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@" The Error is: %@",error.debugDescription);
        if(self.delegate)
        {
            [self.delegate didReceiveProcessingError];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        recessionTips   =   [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *tips = [json objectForKey:@"Info"];


        for (int i=0; i<tips.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *tip = (NSDictionary*)[tips objectAtIndex:i];

            RecessionTipModel *recessionTip    =   [[RecessionTipModel alloc] init];


          recessionTip.tipdescription         =   (NSString*)[tip objectForKey:@"email"];
           recessionTip.username               =   (NSString*)[tip objectForKey:@"name"];

            [recessionTips addObject:recessionTip];
        }

        if(self.delegate)
        {
            [self.delegate didReceiveRecessionTips:recessionTips];
        }

    }

}
```

the error is:

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)

any one can help me Plz?

Comment: The language is called Objective-C. XCode is just the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

That is no valid JSON. Who ever created it created a string enclosed by quotation marks and escaped all quotation marks within this string.

So if you can then convince your data source to deliver valid JSON. If you can't then convert all \" to simple " and cut off the leading (and tailing) quotation mark.

And then feed the JSON serializer with the valid JSON string